# Dissolving not based on attribute in GeoPandas

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, dissolve

I would like to dissolve a shapefile regardless of attribute content using `geopandas`. The regular dissolve can be accomplished with something like this:

```py
import geopandas

all = geopandas.read_file(r'Inputs\All.shp')    
all = all.dissolve(by='topology')    
all.to_file(driver='ESRI Shapefile', filename=r'Intermediate\All_dissolved.shp')
```

But the above is using the *'topology'* field to aggregate. I have also noticed that the `all.dissolve()` function exits with an error, indicating that the `by` parameter is required.

How can I dissolve regardless of the attribute in GeoPandas?

Comment: does it work with an empty string or a True as value for `by` maybe?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You will lose all attributes but [`unary_union`](http://geopandas.org/geometric_manipulations.html#GeoSeries.unary_union) will return one big multipolygon which you can turn into singleparts with `.geoms`:

```
import geopandas as gpd
df = gpd.read_file(r"C:\Test\New_Shapefile.shp")
df.plot(cmap='cool')
```

[image]

```
df2 = gpd.geoseries.GeoSeries([geom for geom in df.unary_union.geoms])
df2.plot(cmap='cool')
```

[image]

(You can also add a column, fill with some value and then dissolve by

```
df['dissolvefield'] = 1
df2 = df.dissolve(by='dissolvefield')
df3 = gpd.geoseries.GeoSeries([geom for geom in df2.geometry.iloc[0].geoms])
```

)