# Dissolve lines that intersect after attending some dataframe (atributte table) conditions

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, numpy

I need to dissolve all Linestrings from a `geodataframe` that intersects each other after attending some tabular conditions: 1)have the same `ID` and 2) have the same `opening` year.
I am working with `geopandas`.
The data look like this:

```
    id    opening    geometry
0   30    2020       LINESTRING (45.01679 -12.12937, 45.01681 -12...
1   101   1999       LINESTRING (37.02849 -10.65968, 37.02849 -10...
2   30    2019       LINESTRING (47.10667 -15.49339, 47.10665 -15...
3   101   1999       LINESTRING (41.64170 -12.45764, 41.64180 -12...
4   135   2020       LINESTRING (45.31902 -9.76800, 45.31907 -9.7...
```

I have tried the following code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import shapely

gdf_sof = gpd.read_file('your_path/your_file')

# Concatenate the conected segments
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
for id in gdf_sof.id.unique():
  print(id)
  unique_id = gdf_sof.loc[gdf_sof.id == id]
  print(unique_id.shape)
  gdf_sof_id = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
  for dt in unique_id.opening.unique():
    print(dt)
    unique_oppening = unique_id.loc[unique_id.opening == dt]
    dissolved = gpd.geoseries.GeoSeries([geom for geom in unique_oppening.unary_union.geoms])
    gdf_sof_id = pd.concat([gdf_sof_id, dissolved], ignore_index=True, axis=0)
  gdf.concat(gdf_sof_id, ignore_index=True, axis=0, inplace=True)

gdf.shape
```

But got this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: 'LineString' object has no attribute 'geoms'
```

I also tried the solution below:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import shapely
from shapely.ops import linemerge

gdf_sof = gpd.read_file('your_path/your_file')

# Dissolve the connected segments
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
for id in gdf_sof.id.unique():
  unique_id = gdf_sof.loc[gdf_sof.id == id]
  gdf_sof_id = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
  for dt in unique_id.opening.unique():
    unique_opening = unique_id.loc[unique_id.opening == dt]
    shp = shapely.get_parts(unique_opening.geometry)
    dissolved = linemerge(shp)
    gdf_dissolved = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'id': [id],
                                      'opening': [dt],
                                      'geometry':dissolved},
                                      geometry = 'geometry', 
                                      crs = gdf_sof.crs)
    gdf_sof_id = pd.concat([gdf_sof_id, gdf_dissolved], ignore_index=True, axis=0)
  gdf = pd.concat([gdf, gdf_sof_id], ignore_index=True, axis=0)

gdf.shape
```

But it didn't work. The final gdf `(973,3)` dissolved segments that don't touch.
[image: All selected segments in the image are just one row in the attribute table. I need them separated!]

All selected segments in the image are just one row in the attribute table. I need them separated!

Comment: I dont understand your code fully but the error is because unary_unioning a LineString does not produce a multilinestring. And you can't do `.geoms` on a LineString. Try adding an if statement, like:  `uu = unique_oppening.unary_union`
    `if uu.geom_type=="MultiLineString":
        dissolved = gpd.GeoSeries(list(uu.geoms))`
`else:` return the LineString unchanged?

Comment: @BERA the code I put on this question was based on your reply to [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296663/dissolve-not-based-on-attribute-in-geopandas). What I want besides your answer there is to consider "id" and "opening" attributes into the dissolve. I guess inserting this "if condition" that you suggest will solve the error, but I won't get what I need because all my rows have `LineString` geometry and none of them are `MultiLineString`.

Comment: @BERA, I shared the data, but a gentle moderator deleted my answer. I also don't see your answer anymore, I don't know if you deleted it or him.
Last try: https://github.com/marlonfs/dissolve-roads